# randint usage in Learn Python the hard way exercise 43

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am having trouble with the randint usage of exercise 43 in Learn python the hard way [link to exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html). Assuming I follow Zed Shaw's code perfectly in all other parts of the program, and I have `from random import randint`, when I run the program and type the 3 digit passcode into the keypad, it returns a "BZZZZEDDD!". Here is that section of code:

```
class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room"
        print "for more Gothons that might be hiding.  It's dead quiet, too quiet."
        print "You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the"
        print "neutron bomb in its container.  There's a keypad lock on the box"
        print "and you need the code to get the bomb out.  If you get the code"
        print "wrong 10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't"
        print "get the bomb.  The code is 3 digits."
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print "BZZZZEDDD!"
            guesses += 1
            guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == code:
            print "The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting gas out."
            print "You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as you can to the"
            print "bridge where you must place it in the right spot."
            return 'the_bridge'
        else:
            print "The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a sickening"
            print "melting sound as the mechanism is fused together."
            print "You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothons blow up the"
            print "ship from their ship and you die."
            return 'death'
```

Lets say in the `guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")` when running the program I type in "368".
Shouldn't that be within the parameters of `code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))` and be TRUE for `if guess ==code:`? Instead it runs it as if guess != code and returns a "BZZZZEDDD!"

Comment: You might have to cast guess to an int

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser actually they are both strings.

Comment: The generated code is random. How did you get the idea that "368" must be a correct solution? It might be, but most probably it is not.

Comment: The code seems correct for me. I don't get why you think it is wrong?

Comment: @lcfseth: Ooops, you're right.  I misread `guess` and `guesses`.

Comment: Minor comment, instead of several prints, you could just add \n to make a break line in the same string. Keeps IMO a clean code.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess of 368 is within the possible range for the code, but that's not what the while loop is checking. The line

```
code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
```

will generate a string of three random digits. The code could be anything between 111 and 999 (except there can be no zeroes) and you have no way of knowing exactly what it is as the program currently stands. At the bottom of the lesson, under Study Drills, the author says:

> 1. Add cheat codes to the game so you can get past the more difficult
>      rooms. I can do this with two words on one line.

Presumably, this code is one of the rooms he's talking about. Try adding something that will give you a hint of the code.

Comment: Ohhh! I thought I was supposed to type in a code that I was to randomly generate myself. It works when I just type in "code". Thank you.

Comment: It works if you type "code" as guess? According to the code you've shown us there is no way this could work. It would work if you had written `if guess == "code" and guesses < 10:`.